# Executing Jquery POP up from a link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a script from jquery that executes a pop up from a button. I want to use a href link instead but can't figure out the syntax to do so. Going through the jQuery documentation I can't find anything specifying what I am try to do.

the link is:`<a href="#" class="connect_link" id="create-user">Join the mailling List</a>`

The current code i have is:`$( "#create-user" )
            .button()
            .click(function() {
                $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
            });`
I assumed that if you changed `.button()` to `.link()` it would work but no such luck.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
$( "#create-user" ).click(function() { $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" ); });
```

And it'll work. `$("#create-user")` selects your  element, and then doing `.click()` binds the click action to that element.